# Azure DevOps Work items board, cant show nesting / hierarchy

Tags: azure-devops, nested, scrum, workitem, epic

I am new to DevOps and Scrum/Agile.

My question is about nesting of parent-child work items.

I am on Azure DevOps.  I am on the Work items board (not "Boards" or "Backlogs" or "Sprints")

I have added two Epics.  I have added a Feature and made it a Child of one of the Epics.

However, when I look at the Work items page, this nesting/hierarchy does not appear at all, and I cant' find a way to show it.

I three items on my list, the two Epics and the one Feature.  All just at root of the list.

I want this to be nested.  The Feature attached to my Epic should be underneath my Epic. It is not.  Everything is just dumped on the list.

This strikes me as silly / stupid (but like I said, I'm new to this).  This should be like File Explorer, with everything nested.

What is the point of having Parent/Child relationships if it is impossible to visually see them?  Am I missing something?

How do I get these items to nest properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Work Items page will not show the Parent/Child relationships. This page is used to quickly find work items assigned to you or pivot or filter work items based on other criteria, such as work items that you follow, that you're mentioned in, or that you viewed or updated. Please refer [the Work Items page document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

If you want to see the Parent/Child relationships clearly, you can check it in the Backlog page. You can enable the Parents option here when you choose the Feature level: [image]
You can also choose the Epic level and it will show all children.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  I realize I can't change how DevOps works, but if the Work Items page is the main or first page you see, and it's where you enter Work Items, it strikes me as a great place to have nesting.  But it is what it is.  Thanks again eh.